# Cloud firestore bandwidth exhausted error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are using cloud firestore as our database and getting following error when rate of parallel reads from database increases.

```
details:  "Bandwidth exhausted"    
message:  "8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Bandwidth exhausted"    
stack:  "Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Bandwidth exhausted
at callErrorFromStatus (/usr/service/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
at Http2CallStream.call.on (/usr/service/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:79:34)
at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:198:15)
at process.nextTick (/usr/service/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:100:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:9)"
```

We couldn't find what is the rate limits. Could you please let me know what are the read rate limits and in which cases firestore returns Bandwidth exhausted error?

Note: Billing is enabled in our project. The problem is we can't find what limit we are reaching.

Answer (score 0):

The `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` error indicates that the project exceeded either its quota or the region/multi-region capacity, so probably your app is doing more reads than expected given what you described. You can check more details in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors).

You can check the free quotas and the standard limits on this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) and the pricing for what exceeds those numbers on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing). It's important to note that, if you choose to allow your app to go further than the free quotas, you must enable billing for your Cloud Platform project, here is a [how to](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project).

You can also check how much your app is actually using of the quotas on app engine on the section below:

[image]

Hope This helps.

Answer (score -1):

If your are reading all data from Firebase, this issue happens to you, I had the same problem for reading all data from firebase, after a while, I figured out if we stop this process and run a new process we can pass the error and continue the job.

then I used child-process and it helped me:

- I did write a parent script and a child script,
- Parent script runs child script as a child-process,
- The child goes through a collection until get [8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED] error, then send a message to parent to inform it from the error.
- Then parent kills child and create a new one and tells it where to start reading again.

This is a solution that works 100 percent, but it's a little advance and beginners-intermediates may could not able to implement it.

update:
I have written a complete instruction on GitHub Gist for this issue, you can check it:
https://gist.github.com/navidshad/973e9c594a63838d1ebb8f2c2495cf87